# Parse CloudCode always calling success - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Im using Parse CloudCode (Android), and it always seems to return with the success method, even when it SHOULD return an error in some cases. Im using Parse SDK 1.9.2 on Android.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendRequest",function(request, response) 
{

var username1 = request.params.username1;

var query = new Parse.Query("UserFriends");
query.equalTo("username1", username1);
query.find({
success: function(results) 
{
  var sum = "5";
  response.success(sum);
},
error: function() {
  response.error("movie lookup failed");
}
});

});
```

**Android method: (Called when a button is clicked)**

```
public void parseCloud(String s1,String s2)
{
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("username1", s1);
    params.put("username2", s2);

    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendRequest", params, new FunctionCallback<String>()
    {
          public void done(String result, ParseException e) 
          {
            if (e == null) 
            {
              // result is "Hello world!"
                Log.i("ParseCloud:Success:",result.toString());
            }else
            {
                Log.i("ParseCloud:Error:",e.getMessage().toString());
            }
          }
    });
}
```

**Edit** Ive also tried to change the error method on the CloudCode, but it still returns with the success method

```
 error: function(err) {
  //response.error("movie lookup failed");
  response.error();
}
```

Comment: What cases do you mean by "even when it SHOULD"? Getting no results from the query does not mean it's an error and will send a success.

Comment: If i query for a column that doesnt exist? Say i dont have a column called "username" in my Class, does it call success/error in that case?